# Racket iterative precedes procedure

Tags: racket

I'm trying to write an iterative procedure called precedes which inputs a list of identifiers and two identifiers from the list, and returns #t if the first of these identifiers occurs before the second, otherwise #f.

This is my code.

```
(define (precedes id1 id2 lst)
  (define (iter lst n x)
    (cond ((null? lst) #f)
          ((eq? (car lst) n) #t)
              (else (iter (cdr lst) (+ 1 n) x))))
  (iter '() 0 1))
```

An example output of this procedure is `(precedes 'e 'c '(d b e a c g f)) = #t`

Thanks.

Comment: You're passing an empty list to `iter`, hence the `#f` output produced by `(null? lst)`. Also, if lst is meant to be a list of identifier symbols, it doesn't make much sense checking for equality between its elements and `n` (a number). `x`, on the other hand, is completely unused in your `iter` procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexander's remarks are correct; also, you don't keep the information whether you found id1. Here's an example how you could do:

```lisp
(define (precedes id1 id2 lst)
  (define (iter lst foundid1)
    (printf "~a ~a\n" lst foundid1) ; for debugging
    (cond ((null? lst)
           #f)  ; never found id2 so #f
          ((eq? (car lst) id2)
           foundid1) ; found id2 so result is whether we found id1 before         
          ((eq? (car lst) id1)
           (iter (cdr lst) #t)) ; found id1 so iterate, set found flag to #t
          (else
           (iter (cdr lst) foundid1)))) ; found nothing, iterate
  (iter lst #f))
```

and here's the output:

```
> (precedes 'e 'c '(d b e a c g f))
(d b e a c g f) #f
(b e a c g f) #f
(e a c g f) #f
(a c g f) #t
(c g f) #t
#t

> (precedes 'x 'c '(d b e a c g f))
(d b e a c g f) #f
(b e a c g f) #f
(e a c g f) #f
(a c g f) #f
(c g f) #f
#f

> (precedes 'x 'y '(d b e a c g f))
(d b e a c g f) #f
(b e a c g f) #f
(e a c g f) #f
(a c g f) #f
(c g f) #f
(g f) #f
(f) #f
() #f
#f
```